10/100 Ethernet PHY: What is this capacitor for?
10/100 Ethernet PHYs such as ENC28J60 and DM9051 recommend the following external components on each pair. What is the circled capacitor for? Any referencing or balancing that it provides would seem to be insignificant compared to the other capacitor? (Transformer impedance should be small. If it's anywhere near 50 ohms, then we have bigger problems.)

And of course we care because there is significant cost: in addition to the capacitor itself, we now need 2 single-ended 50 ohm resistors instead of 1 differential 100 ohm resistor.
Update 1
I have tried removing the extra capacitor from a DM9051 PHY. Plugging in various cables and equipment does not reveal any problems. It links up at 10M and 100M, over a 2ft and 500ft cable, with another similarly modified DM9051. Also both cables work with a Netgear at 10M and 100M, and, at 10M, with an ENC28J60 (which only supports 10M).
So the design has some margin without the capacitor, that may be sufficient in many applications, especially 10Mbps applications. The transformers I am using are not fancy (they cost $0.05 each).
This so far aligns with my analysis showing that whatever effect the capacitor is having, it is very subtle. And whatever problem it is solving, it is likely not the most cost-effective solution, but maybe just something that made sense historically?
Update 2
I looked at both pairs with a differential 200MHz scope. With this scope, it is hard to see any difference in signal quality with or without the capacitor. For example, here is the Tx pair (pins 1 & 2).



@Jasen the 1.8v and decoupling cap on the center tap should do a fine job keeping the PHY side center voltage at a clean 1.8v. The transformer is about 5mm from the IC.

https://www.skyworksinc.com/Blog/2022/09/Timing-101-04 may be useful

I cannot know for a fact but usually a bypass capacitors at some location location is suggested by chip manufacturers for a reason, because if they didn't, they would get angry calls from customers that the chip fails to perform as expected because they did not get the hint to apply a capacitor anyway from any other source.
And, this capacitor is almost always suggested in every Ethernet circuit with current mode and voltage mode PHYs.
For CM PHY, ripple of 3.3V (or other) supply at the transformer center tap or at the termination resistors will affect the signal. The resistor converts the current to a voltage signal.
If the circuit is for a PHY receiver with external biasing and external termination, the capacitor between resistors helps to keep the common mode DC bias stable, as remember that the transformer has inductance from center tap to the output terminals and any imbalance in the transformer can convert DM signal and/or noise to CM signal and/or noise.
Your tests of simply the Ethernet link works with some other device.
It does not tell you if the device is compliant and within all the specs required for it to be an Ethernet device, or outside of specs, but just works.
Also even if it is within Ethernet specs, you have no guarantees if the EMI/EMC tests pass or not if the capacitor is important, maybe for other reasons than Ethernet.
And the schematics don't show any PCB layout problems, like you said, your layout could have no issues without that capacitor but some other design might.
You can always draw the capacitor in the schematics but leave the capacitor not mounted during manufacture when you have verified it works as expected without it. And then you don't need to redo the PCB if you happen to need it.
And if you are questioning the use of a single bypass capacitor used for high speed signal termination bypassing at a logical schematic level instead of physical PCB layout level, you should also question each and every other bypass cap too. It is possible that a chip with 10 pairs of supply/groung pins does not really need one bypass capacitor per pair of supply pins but you do it anyway as adding a few 5 cent parts is nothing compared to the engineering time to optimize the circuit to run at the minimum possible set of bypass caps and their best placement. But if you do make a billion boards then cost of capacitors matter and you also must do proper analysis which bypass caps can be left out while still being able to pass Ethernet, EMI, EMC, safety, isolation etc compliance test specifications.

In summary, it's an informative circuit element that (1) makes it easier to understand how the PHY open-drain outputs work and (2) might provide some sort of EMI or robustness guarantee within some set of assumptions about board layout, much like the typical recommendation to put a bypass cap on every VDD/VSS pair. That makes sense; I'll accept that.

It provides a local ground reference for the resistors, which should be placed near the PHY chip.  It could also be tied to +1.8V (or whatever VCC is; usually 3.3V), but the capacitor is sufficient as the transformer provides DC reference.
It cannot be optimized down to a single differential resistor, because the common mode needs to be terminated.  Typically the PHY output drivers are open-drain type, and the two connections are transmission line stubs either end of the transformer (and including the wires that make up the transformer itself).
Minimum value is determined by those transmission line lengths, namely the low-frequency equivalent inductance thereof (which in the transformer, might also be specified as leakage inductance).  Presumably they want \$C \gg \frac{L}{R^2}\$, where L is the stray+leakage of each path, and R is the termination resistor.
PHYs with a full-bridge style output stage (mostly 1000BASE-T but some 100BASE-T transmitters are using this now too) can have the common mode determined by internal circuitry and thus the CT (of resistors and transformer) don't need to be biased (to VCC), and just the bypass cap suffices.  (They probably aren't going fully without a center tap, because the CT sinks CM current through the isolation barrier, current that would otherwise have to be handled by the output amplifiers, and compromise balance, immunity and ESD handling.)

Why do the resistors need a ground reference when the signal into them already has a high quality local ground reference provided by the transformer center tap?

Good point that the transformer has stray inductance. However, as noted in the question, there are much bigger problems if the effective transformer impedance is not small in comparison to R. For 10Mbps at least, getting a higher frequency transformer is going to be far more cost effective than redendant decoupling that can only help a few percent.

Like I said, transmission lines. Ground is not everywhere, ground is local. A lot of what we do in high-speed design concerns mitigating voltage differences across a PCB, or between PCBs. As for transformers, there are many impedances in a transformer, consider an equivalent circuit like this for instance: https://www.seventransistorlabs.com/Images/XfmrEquiv.png you'll have to be more specific. For 10M alone, hardly anything is needed, but can you even find PHYs for that anymore (exclusive 10, not 10/100)?

Standard Ethernet transformers are rated to have a max loss of 1dB @ 100MHz, which is an amplitude loss of 11%. There is no "across the PCB" here. All components are within 5mm of one another, which is nothing at these low frequencies. At 100Mbps or 1Gbps, the max operating frequency is 62.5MHz, so the maximum amplitude loss is 7%. Half of this is on the PHY side. So any mitigation of this is going to (at best) make the signal 3.5% better and only on the TX side. I am questioning the cost/benefit analysis.

Ok, not much on board, that's good. What about the wire length within the transformer? You're not counting amplitude correctly however. CM/DM is different modes entirely, and notice I didn't mention loss. It's more complicated than that. Simply removing components and testing a connection, isn't sufficient proof here -- Ethernet is a very robust signaling method and you need proper signal analysis to assess performance.

Re: "Simply removing components and testing a connection, isn't sufficient proof here." Good point. I've also added some scope pictures. Yes, it's possible that there are some robustness/compliance issues that my scope is not fancy enough to measure, or that maybe are only an issue on larger boards.

You show a differential waveform, yes. What about each signal (P/N) alone? Looks like you'll need more bits (i.e. expand the scale to 500 or 200mV/div) to show it in enough detail.


I have tried removing the extra capacitor from a DM9051 PHY. Plugging in various cables and equipment does not reveal any problems.

I doubt that. Well-designed communication systems are conservative with what they transmit/send - i.e. they strive to have outputs that only in the worst circumstance are at the edge of what's allowed, and typically are much better than that. They are also tolerant of out-of-spec inputs while still maintaining link - unless the standard explicitly disallows that in some scenarios, like link negotiation.
All that you may be experiencing is that both ends of the link have PHYs that can work with below-standard signals - just as an example. We can't know because you didn't measure anything.
You'll need a full-function Ethernet tester that can verify that this capacitor-less implementation is in fact standards-compliant. Current models rent for $1k/week as a rough ballpark. You'll also need an EMC test.
The "plug it in" tests are valuable - that's why we have plugfests. But they are in addition to an implementation that is verified to be standards-compliant. They do not verify standards compliance, but they do ensure that there are no problems interoperating with other devices on the market.
Many standards are complex, and the verification/test tools always play catch-up with newest standards, errata, and recognized fielded workarounds. So it is entirely possible to have a nominally compliant solution that still will have trouble interoperating with some widely deployed product. That's what plug-in testing and plugfests are for. They only test that your device has no problem interoperating with the particular test setup used in a plugfest, not that it is generally "problem-free".

And whatever problem it is solving, it is likely not the most cost-effective solution

You must be making an awful lot of those devices to amortize the cost of your engineering time just asking this question here and looking for answers relative to the cost of that capacitor. Unless you work for free :)

The transformers I am using are not fancy (they cost $0.05 each).

Can you share what transformers are those? DigiKey sells nothing current below about $0.30 qty 1000.

I am using these transformers that LCSC sells for $0.05 @ 2.4k. I have also used these transformers that Digi-Key sells for $0.14 @ 1k.

Fair point that it takes some engineering time to clean up a design. Working with a messy design also takes engineering time. Every extra component has to be placed and routed in every prototype and provides a chance for a mistake to crop up.
